# How to pair values from 2 related MySQL tables in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to output question with multiple choice options (using custom wordpress tables). I have separate tables for questions (`q_question`) and answers (`q_answer`).

My earlier approach was like (getting all relevant questions and then querying for every question's options)-

```
foreach ($all_questions as $question) {
// Running SQL to get options specific for this specific question id
}
```

But I thought, it will flood server with multiple queries (as I am trying to output 300 questions in one round).

So (to save server load from multiple SQL queries) **now I am trying to get all relevant options in single query**. For this, first I selected and stored the desired question ids in `$qid_list` from my question table. Then to get all related options/answers in a single query as -

```
$ans_list = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,question_id,answer,correct FROM {$wpdb->prefix}q_answer WHERE question_id IN ($qid_list)");
```

The problem is that **I am not able to understand how can I pair question with its related options with this approach.**
300 Questions means about 1200 options, so is there any way to arrange them in some array/sub-array, so that they can be further used?

ps - I don't know what should be the correct title for this question.

Comment: I guess you have loop all 1200 record. make a group based on question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map i.e. associative array:

```
$ans_map = array();
foreach($ans_list as $ans) {
    $question_id = $ans->question_id;
    if(!isset($ans_map[$question_id])) $ans_map[$question_id] = array();
    $ans_map[$question_id][] = $ans;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($ans_map);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems, in wordpress, I can't use it as such. I had to customize it like `$ans_map[$ans->question_id])`. Then it worked.